# Reloading bootstrap with Grails

Tags: grails

Is there a way in Grails to run the contents of BootStrap.groovy after it has been changed without restarting the app?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with the [`console` plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/console).  I'd highly recommend this plugin for any development environment because it's so useful for running ad-hoc code inside a running server.

To rerun your BootStrap `init` closure, browse to the web-based console at `http://localhost:8080/appname/console`.  Enter the following in the console:

```
def servletCtx = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder.servletContext
def myBootstrapArtefact = grailsApplication.getArtefacts('Bootstrap')[-1]
myBootstrapArtefact.referenceInstance.init(servletCtx)
```

Comment: How could you run this if you have environments defined in your init closure?